# One route to handle new url and legacy url

Tags: asp.net, routes

I am using the asp.net routing in a webforms application and I need to map the new url's and the legacy url's to the same route.

localhost/blog/?financial-literacy-efficacy

localhost/blog/financial-literacy-efficacy

The legacy url's have a question mark in front of the query string and the routing /{slug} is not picking it up.

i have tried something like this with no luck

```
  routes.MapPageRoute("blog-slug", _
                      "blog/?{slug}", _
                      "~/blogArticles/Default.aspx")
```

Is this possible?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the routes will not accept anything after the ? as part of the page being routed to since by definition the ? separates the query string from the resource in the URL. One way that might work is

```
routes.MapPageRoute("blog-slug", _
                    "blog/", _
                    "~/blogArticles/Default.aspx")
```

But the "financial-literacy-efficacy" value will instead be a key since it is ?x not ?slug=x. However, since that is the legacy url, there might already exist some portion of your code that checks keys in query strings as opposed to values since most dynamic webforms legacy urls look soemthing like

```
blog/?slug=x
```

And then they check Request.Querystring["slug"]. You would need to provide more information in your question if that causes you trouble.

Comment: That makes sense, I guess I will have to figure out another way to do it. Thanks.